# How to switch from termtrans to !termtrans in vim with solarized colortheme?

Tags: vim, command, color-scheme

When I toggle the colortheme in vim from the dark to the light background, I'd also like to switch the termtrans option to off (and back on again), since I cannot change the background-color of the terminal. How can I accomplish this?

Context: I did set my terminal to the solarized colour palette with the dark background and transparency. I often code in vim with the solarized colortheme, also with the dark option. Since my terminal is transparent, I did set the option for transparent backgrounds. I like to write non-code text with the light color option. Therefore I can quickly toggle the color with the -Key. However, since termtrans has been set, the dark color of the terminal shows through and the terminal is not light at all then.

Comment: gnome-terminal under Fedora, Terminal.app and iTerm2.app under Mac OS X.6/7/8, but that should not matter: Since the activation of the background-color drawing of the solarized theme will overpaint the terminal background in any case. The question is how to switch the termtrans option.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed change your terminal settings.
But it's simpler to ask for a light solarized theme again.

map your toggle to (I assume you use  to toggle):
`map <F5> :set background=light<CR>:let solarized_termtrans=0<CR>:colorscheme solarized<CR>`